# Understanding DNSCrypt Proxy resolver URLs

Tags: dns

After downloading DNSCrypt Proxy, I noticed that the public resolvers it can forward requests to are not identified with IP addresses, but with sdns:// URLs like

sdns://AgcAAAAAAAAABzEuMC4wLjGgENk8mGSlIfMGXMOlIlCcKvq7AVgcrZxtjon911-ep0cg63Ul-I8NlFj4GplQGb_TTLiczclX57DvMV8Q-JdjgRgSZG5zLmNsb3VkZmxhcmUuY29tCi9kbnMtcXVlcnk

for Cloudflare's DNS servers.
I wanted to understand how I could manually resolve those URLs to IP addresses and create my own.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I'm a dummy.
Those sdns://... strings are called 'stamps' and documentation for them can be found here https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/stamps
And creating your own can be done with this tool https://dnscrypt.info/stamps/